# Trouble with Vlookup on power queries?

Tags: excel, vlookup, powerquery

So it's a simple function,

---

=vlookup(a23,sheet3!a:e,5,0)

---

I have two vlookup both returning from a power query, one works and the other doesn't both are formatted in exactly the same way and both query's are very similar (no obvious differences)

---

[image: Query one (Sheet 2)]

---

[image: Query Two (Sheet 3)]

---

[image: Formulas]

---

As you can see the vlookup returns values from sheet3 but not sheet2 even though there are differences. I have re-written it many times and changed the 0 - false in the formula with no changes.

Comment: not sure if related to the problem, but the second screenshot has an extra row of headers and the last two columns 11 and 12 seem to be text instead of numbers.

Comment: I don't think this would be the problem as both query's are formatted as text (minus column 10 in the second screenshot) and both have the same amount of headers its just that screenshot 1 is taken from lower down in the sheet.

Comment: You don't seem to have a `Sheet2`, you have `Sheet1`, `Sheet3`, `Sheet5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your screenshot shows only the formulas, not the error messages. Errors are important when troubleshooting.

Check the data types. It looks as if the data in column A in the second screenshot is numeric, whereas column A in the first screenshot definitely contains text, as can be seen by the trailing / signs in some cells. Ensure that the lookup value and the first column of the lookup table are the same data type. Numbers may look like numbers, but could be stored as text. Non-matching data types will cause the #N/A error.

Comment: The error message is #N/A. All data is formatted in general, I changed both the lookup value and range values to a numeric format but this changed nothing with the error.

Comment: In the end i had to change the format but the problem was that i had to change the format in the query editor as oppose just on the sheet. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check you sheet names, from the screenshots it would appear that `Sheet2` does not exist, only `Sheet1`, `Sheet3`, and `Sheet5`.

EDIT *edited question makes this answer currently irrelevant*

Comment: No formula in that screenshot references sheet2, so what's the problem? It would cause a #REF error, anyway, even in the formula bar, and would be impossible to enter.

Comment: The formula references sheet 3. Sorry in my question it should have been sheet 3 (sheet 2) and sheet 5 (sheet 3).

Comment: @teylyn the question references sheet2 directly `=vlookup(a23,sheet2!a:e,5,0)`

Comment: Sorry, that should be    =vlookup(a23,sheet3!a:e,5,0) as it is in the second screenshot.

Comment: Could it be that the values just do not exist? For example you are looking up company id "3", if it can't find it it will return an error. Which is why it is working from `Sheet3` because from the screenshots I can see the value `3` exists, but it may not in `Sheet5`